# Is Hakai a technique impossible for Goku to master?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last chapter of the Dragon Ball Super manga,

> Beerus says that for using hakai he has to think only in destruction

Goku apparently tried to use hakai in the past, but it seems that he didnt master it since he says he failed using it.

Also, according to Dragon Ball, Goku can use the flying nimbus because he has a pure heart. Can a person like Goku with a pure heart do what Beerus says he has to do to use hakai?

Is Hakai a technique impossible for Goku to master?

Answer (score 1):

No, for now. Hakai is a technique that can only be achieved by a god of destruction. If you are not a god it is impossible to master the hakai technique. But that's only looking from the anime. In the manga Goku is able to learn hakai in a fight against fused zamasu. Sadly in the manga debut Toriyama hasn't confirmed Goku learning hakai to be canon.

Answer (score 1):

Goku can not and probably will not ever be able to use the hakai. However, with the current manga being where it is at, it looks like Vegeta will learn how to do it if the torch ever gets passed on to him. He already learned the way of the god of destruction with his new ultra ego form, the only thing holding him back from being a god if destruction is the hakai. In SDBH, I believe Goku could use the hakai, but that's just comp Goku.